# Finding repeating patterns in multi-variate data

Tags: algorithm, finance, quantitative-finance, computational-finance

Say I have the following dataset:

```
 time_m = {A:1, B:2, C:3, D:10}; 
 time_n = {A:6, B:2, C:12, D:18}; 
 time_p = {A:1, B:2, C:9, D:17}; 
 time_q = {A:1, B:2, C:9, D:2}.
```

As you can see, I have 4 variables `A, B, C, D` whose values are measured at time points `m, n, p, q`.

I want to find time points in the data when the variables had the same values again. For example, if I want to maximise the number of variables, the answer is:

```
{A, B, C} at {time_p, time_q}
```

Or, if I want to maximise the number of time points, the answer becomes:

```
{A, B} at {time_m, time_p, time_q}
```

For a little bit more context, say `A, B, C, D` are stock prices and I am interested to analyse historical data to find when a subset of stocks reached the same values again.

How can I do this? Is the algorithm for this, or a similar one, implemented anywhere?

Comment: how big is your observation data `{ A, B, C, D, ... }` dimensionality? Scaling of this problem is **`[m,n]`** and can be a performance issue for a universally working solution over a long-term time-series quantitative modelling across a wider/multi-assets' landscapes to cover [stocks,FX-spots,options,futures,...].

Comment: Definitely use `Random Forest` probably the easiest and most efficient to implement. `sklearn` also has a nice implementation if you are using Python http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html